# Hadoop classpath psudo-distributed mode

Tags: java, hadoop, classpath

I'm running some simple tests of Hadoop locally in psudo-distributed mode. But the reducer is giving me a ClassNotFoundException.

I've got the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` set as such:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/davidparks21/hadoop/FruggMapreduceJobs.jar:/home/davidparks21/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/lib/*
```

And I've got all of these classes in `$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/`

What am I missing?

Comment: can you post the error message? without error message others cant help easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to restart mapreduce (stop-mapred.sh/start-mapred.sh) so that it loaded and distrubted my new jars appropriately.

Comment: I'm not sure what it says of me that I just found this question and used it to solve my current classpath problem, and I both asked and answered this question not 20 days previously.